# VBA not able to discern between empty cells, numeric cells, and text?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to read cells in VBA and do certain things based on the contents of them. However, VBA is unable to accurately determine if the contents of a cell are blank, numeric, or text. It will think that cells with only a '1' in them are blank, and cells with text are blank. If it makes a difference, I turn off all screen updating and the like when this runs.

Please see code below:

```
Function IsNumber(ByRef expression As Variant) As Boolean    
    IsNumber = Not IsEmpty(expression) And IsNumeric(expression)    
End Function

Function IsText(ByRef expression As Variant) As Boolean    
    IsText = Not IsEmpty(expression) And Not IsNumeric(expression)    
End Function

Sub RA()
    Dim cell As Range    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(lastrow, lastCol - 1))
     End With

    For i = 3 To lastrow
        Set c = Cells(i, 3)
        Select Case True
            Case S1_Func(c)
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub

Function S1_Func(c As Variant)
    Dim SR As Worksheet
    Set SR = Worksheets("Financials")
    Dim c2 As Range    
    Set c2 = c.Offset(0, 1)

    If IsNumber(c2.Value2) Then
        Select Case True
            Case SR.Cells(i, 5).Value2 = "LY"
        End Select
    ElseIf IsText(c2.Value2) Then
        Cells(i, 72).Value2 = "Incorrect"
    End If
End sub
```

Comment: Just curious - why use `Select Case` when you can write out `If IsNumber(c2.Value2) = True Then`? Seems to be adding unnecessary extra lines.

Comment: That's only part of the code, @dwirony. There are over 20 if/else + case statements in there, which is why I brought it down into the function

Answer (score 1):

Updated after discussion below.

```
Function IsNumber(ByRef expression As Variant) As Boolean    
    IsNumber = expression <> "" And IsNumeric(expression)    
End Function

Function IsText(ByRef expression As Variant) As Boolean    
    IsText = expression <> "" And Not IsNumeric(expression)    
End Function
```

Original post:

There are some mixed problem in your code. The `Select` statement have several issues and is very misleading. In this case you can't use `Select`. `If` is your best option. Try something like this:

```
Sub Example()
    If Len(Value) = 0 Then
        'Empty
    ElseIf IsNumeric(Value) Then
        'Numeric
    Else
        'Alphanumeric
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That's only part of the code, Sam. There are over 20 if/else + case statements in there, which is why I brought it down into the function

Comment: Ignore the Select statement for now. You are using IsNumber and IsText. Those functions aren't available in VBA. Is it something you have declared elsewhere?

Comment: I have. They're in the top of the code that I pasted above.

Comment: Sorry. A bit blind. IsEmpty is not what you need. That is used to determine if something has been initialized. Test it with (expression = "") instead.

Comment: Also these evaluations in OP's question are written as though VBA has short circuit logic evaluation. It doesn't.

Comment: @brad I don't see the issue here? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Sam, I got it working. Thank you for the solution. Would you like to submit it as the official answer?